# Selenium getText() will return the string, but won't pass the condition

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext

I'm trying to test form fields on a dynamic page. The fields might occasionally be in a different location, and the id will always be `"input_" + some number`.
For example - `input_0 = firstname, input_1 = lastname,` etc.

Because of that, I created a loop that goes over all the inputs and checks the values, for example, if the text for this input_i is "First Name", then I will execute the firstname test on this iteration.

Now, I'm printing the text on each loop, and I can see the correct text by this function:

`String inputText = inputTextElement.getText(); returns "First Name"`.
`System.out.println(inputText); is printing "First Name"`.
So far so good.

But when I'm moving forward to the condition - if (`inputText == "First Name"`), the condition returns false.

I'm out of ideas for the cause here. Any suggestions?

I tried inputText.toString() as well, just in case.
No luck here, either.

Comment: If it is about comparing `String`s, use `inputText.equals("First Name")` instead of comparing (more than just the value) by `==`.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I just realized I should've used .equals(). :)